# Converting T-SQL's date functions to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to convert this MS SQL Server code to MySQL but I am not getting the same date I would get in MS SQL Server. Does anyone know how to change this code to make it work in MySQL? The '2021-08-03 00:00:00' is a timestamp example being used.

```
SELECT
    FORMAT( DATEADD( DAY, 0, DATEDIFF( DAY, 0, '2021-08-03 00:00:00')), 'd', 'en-us' ) AS 'day'
```

[image]

The MYSQL Code so far.

```
SELECT FORMAT (adddate(datediff(NOW(), ma.Timestamp), INTERVAL 0 DAY), 'd', 'en-us') AS day,
```

Comment: What is MySQL giving you?

Comment: NULL values @squillman

Comment: Could you post the MySQL version so far?

Comment: SELECT FORMAT (adddate(datediff(NOW(), '2021-08-03 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 0 DAY), 'd', 'en-us') AS day; @SOS

Comment: Are you just trying to present any given date/time value as `m/d/y`? Or is there some reason for all the dateadd and datediff noise?

Comment: @need_help12 - Please add it to the question as text, not an image, so it's easier to spot.

Comment: Previous employees created it like that so there is probably some reason to doing all the dateadd and datediff @AaronBertrand

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to present dates in `m/d/y` format in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `dates` (d datetime);

INSERT `dates`(d) VALUES('2021-08-31 03:00'),('2021-11-13 05:40');

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d, '%c/%e/%Y') AS day FROM `dates`;
```

Results:

```
day
----------
8/31/2021
11/13/2021
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce38e790199e2549fc92369a37ff167e)

I knew nothing about this since I can barely spell MySQL, but [looking up `DATE_FORMAT()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_format-function.php) took about two minutes.

As an aside, the existing expression you got from your co-workers is both needlessly complex and [a real drag on performance due to the `FORMAT()` function](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). Try:

```
DECLARE @d date = '2021-08-03T00:00:00.000';
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), @d, 101);
```

If you have a datetime already, that's fine, you can still strip time from it without all the dateadd and datediff noise:

```
DECLARE @d datetime = '2021-08-03T00:00:00.000';
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), @d, 101);
```

Not that I believe [`m/d/y` is a sensible format](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) in the first place, or that you should go out of your way to remove those leading zeroes...